# Header of Sortable CellTable Column not Responsive

Tags: gwt, celltable

I am using GWT 2.5 to create a CellTable with a sortable date column.

My code is as follows:

```
CellTable<Activity> table = new CellTable<Activity>();

table.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<Activity>() {
    @Override
    public String getStyleNames(Activity row, int rowIndex) {
        return TABLE_ROW_STYLE_NAME;
    }
});

// create date column
TextColumn<Activity> dateColumn = new TextColumn<Activity>() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(Activity a) {
        return dateFormat.format(a.getDate());
    }
};
dateColumn.setSortable(true);
dateColumn.setDefaultSortAscending(false);
// add column to table
table.addColumn(dateColumn, myConstants.dateColumnHeader());

// attach provider to table
activityProvider.addDataDisplay(table);

// create sort handler
ListHandler<Activity> sortHandler = new ListHandler<Activity>(activityProvider.getList());
sortHandler.setComparator(dateColumn, new Comparator<Activity>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Activity a1, Activity a2) {
        if (a1 == a2) {
            return 0;
        }

        // compare the date columns
        if (a1 != null) {
            if (a2 != null) {
                long a1Val = a1.getDate().getTime();
                long a2Val = a2.getDate().getTime();
                if (a1Val == a2Val) {
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (a1Val > a2Val) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
});

// add sort handler to table
table.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);

// add date column to table's sort list
table.getColumnSortList().push(dateColumn);

table.setWidth("100%");

getView().getActivityPanel().add(table);
```

With this code, the data is displayed in the table and the sorting arrow on the column appears.  However, nothing happens when I click on the sortable column's header.  The sorting order doesn't change, rows are not rearranged.

**Can anyone spot the problem here?**  This code is almost the same as what they have in [Google's own example](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable).

Comment: I have the same problem and **guess it's related to loaded jQuery Mobile** JS?! if I call `table.getColumnSortList().push( someStringColumn )` it displays the table sorted descending on the column. **On column header mouse selection there is some selection border drawn around header and body columns and the sort-icon is not shown. Clicking in the body area then removes this selection, shows the correct sort direction indicator change, but does not sort the table :-(**

Comment: neither `Comparator.compare(...)` nor `Column.getValue(...)` are called after having added some debugging :-/ ... but `getValue(...)` is called on tbody row cell clicks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
    dateColumn.setSortable(true);
    sortHandler.setComparator(dateColumn, new Comparator<ObjectPobject>() {
        public int compare(ObjectPobject o1, ObjectPobject o2) {
            return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
        }
    });
```

Comment: this is same comparator as above, except that you are not checking for null.

one question:  what version of gwt are you using?  i think column sorting may be broken in 2.5rc1

Answer (score 0):

It should be

a1.getDate().getTime().compareTo(a2.getDate().getTime())

or

a1.getDate().after(a2.getDate())

This happens because GWT uses JavaScript comparisons, and compareTo does not work for dates.

Comment: Unfortunately, getting rid of compareTo did not solve the problem :(

Comment: I use the same code as you do and my columns are sorting fine. I use 2.5RC1.